# Creating short, unique object id's in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm making an app similar to instagram using Rails/Mongoid. I want a unique ID that I can use in a url like http://instagr.am/p/DJmU8/

What's the easiest way to do that? Can I derive such an ID from the default BSON ObjectID Mongo creates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try to use first 4 bytes of ObjectID (they will represent timestamp).

But, to be 100% safe, it's better to produce really unique short id, by implementing a counter. You can use separate collection to maintain current value of your counter.

More details on mongo's ObjectID structure can be found here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

As an alternative you can convert convert hex string id representation to a representation based on 36 symbols (26 latin letters + 10 digits). It will obviously be shorter.

It seems, that there is a ruby library, that can do such conversions http://rubyworks.github.com/radix/

Comment: very useful answer, but why 22 latin letters + 10 digits instead of 26 latin letters + 10 digits?

Comment: We can go deeper and use 52 latin letters, 10 digits and some other literals `_-` =) And then with radix64 we get length `log64(2^96) = 16` instead of original `log16(2^96) = 24`.

Answer (score 10):

Why not use [dylang/shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid)?

Install using npm [npmjs.com/package/shortid](http://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid):

```
npm i shortid
```

Then require:

```
const shortid = require('shortid');
```

In mongoose schema:

```js
    new Schema {
        _id: {
            type: String,
            default: shortid.generate
        }
    }
```

or just insert directly:

```
    users.insert({
        _id: shortid.generate()
        name: ...
        email: ...
        });
```

Comment: shortid is now deprecated; use https://github.com/ai/nanoid instead. It's safer and "significantly faster".

Answer (score 7):

You could try Mongoid::Token

https://github.com/thetron/mongoid_token

From the docs:

> This library is a quick and simple way to generate unique, random
>   tokens for your mongoid documents, in the cases where you can't, or
>   don't want to use slugs, or the default MongoDB IDs.
>
> Mongoid::Token can help turn this:
>
> http://myawesomewebapp.com/video/4dcfbb3c6a4f1d4c4a000012/edit
>
> Into something more like this:
>
> http://myawesomewebapp.com/video/83xQ3r/edit

Answer (score 4):

@aav was mention that you can use first 4 bytes, but this value are in seconds and you can get even 10.000 or more insert per seconds. Other thing objectID is Uniq and you need check "when" you get error from duplicate value "Write Concerns"?

> new Date().getTime() - is in milliseconds => 1557702577900 why not use last 4 bytes ? Timestamp in base62 is rqiJgPq

This code look interesting:

https://github.com/treygriffith/short-mongo-id/blob/master/lib/objectIdToShortId.js

Check also ObjectID timestamp parser:

https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

Or you can execute ObjectId().toString() and base of this string create new by [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php/issues/39) [nodejs,php, andmanymore]

> Maybe best options it to use 4-5 bytes from js timestamp and INC from
> bson then hash this value by hids

[image]

```
var id = ObjectID('61e33b8467a45920f80eba52').toString();

console.log("id:", id);
console.log("timestamp:", parseInt(id.substring(0, 8),16).toString());
console.log("machineID:", parseInt(id.substring(8, 14),16) );
console.log("processID:", parseInt(id.substring(14, 18),16) );
console.log("counter:", parseInt(id.slice(-6),16) );

var ObjTimestamp = parseInt(ObjectID2.substring(0, 8),16).toString().slice(-5);
var Counter = parseInt(ObjectID2.slice(-6),16);
//https://github.com/base62/base62.js/
console.log('Final:',base62.encode(parseInt(Counter) + parseInt(ObjTimestamp)  ));
```

Output:

```
vI7o
15V9L
5t4l
```

You can get collision if: more process are running, then consider add PID to unique and when you run multiple instance on different computer

Answer (score 2):

Try gem https://github.com/jffjs/mongoid_auto_inc

Answer (score 0):

The Hashids library is meant for generating IDs like this.  Check it out here ☞ https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb